# Timer in Windows Service not firing ElapsedEventHandler

Tags: c#, timer

I have a windows service written in C# that executes a method correctly.  I added a timer to schedule the method execution and it doesn't seem to fire the ElapsedEventHandler event.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

public LabelService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        }


public void SetTimer()
        {
            DateTime nextRunTime = GetNextRunTime();
            var ts = nextRunTime - DateTime.Now;
            timer.Interval = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Start();
        }

void timer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           // ** never gets here **
            timer.Stop();
              // run some code
            SetTimer();
        }
```

I can run and hit a breakpoint at  `timer.Start();`  so I know that's being done, but it never falls into the timer_Elapsed method.  (For testing I change `ts.TotalMilliseconds` to 1000)  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried moving timer.Interval and timer.AutoReset out of SetTimer() and no change.

Comment: Could you describe more about your class and surrounding code? Is it possible that this code is being run inside something that is being unbloaded from memory before your timer hits off? If the object no longer exists then the event won't fire...

Comment: Sure.  My class is basically what I posted abover, along with a few helper methods that wouldnt have any effect.  It has something to do with the timer because if I call timer_Elapsed right from the OnStart() or Main() it executes fine.  Im hitting breakpoints all the way up until timer.Start() so debugging is working.  I'm missing something...  My class is:  public partial class LabelService : ServiceBase.  I assume that looks correct?

Comment: Are you entirely sure that the event handler is in fact being wired up to the event? Just for funnies, try moving
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

into your SetTimer() method and then 
timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

just after the timer.Stop() in the handler.

Just to see if you can the event...

Comment: Jim - Just tried your suggestion and nothing happens after timer.Start().  I can place a breakpoint there.  It exits SetTimer() and nothing else happens.  Any test code I put at the very beginning of timer_Elapsed never gets hit.  Im pretty sure I added the handler correctly, by typing timer.Elapsed += and hitting tab twice to create the handler.

Comment: @Blaze can you debug this solution in VS with break on all exceptions enabled? If you do not know how to enable this, in the Debug menu, Exceptions then check the option to break when Common Language Runtime Exceptions are thrown.

Perhaps an exception is occuring under the hood.

Comment: I already have that set and am not seeing any CLR exceptions.  The event appears to be wired up, if I break on timer.Start() and mouse over timer > Non-Public members, I can see the correct method tied to the onIntervalElapsed member.  Something is very odd...

Comment: Where does your program begin?
Add a breakpoint at the `timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);` line, because I suspect that may not be happening?

Comment: I call SetTimer() from Main(). Main executes and starts the service code, hits InitializeComponents(), then goes to SetTimer. I have it set this way in order to debug the service. Main look like: #if (!DEBUG) ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun; ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new LabelLoader() }; ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); #else LabelLoader ll = new LabelLoader(); ll.Start(); #endif

Comment: @Edward Black - there is no problem executing timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed); and it appears to be wiring up the event correctly.

Comment: Are you getting any compile-time errors there? Because two of those functions don't have return types. Maybe I'm a bit out of my depth, but I thought you couldn't do that?

Comment: No errors compiling or running.  It just doesnt do anything after leaving SetTimer().  I dont see why having no return type would be an issue.  My main code just does some database inserts so no return type needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments on the question you say you are calling it like this:

```
#if (!DEBUG) 
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun; 
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new LabelLoader() }; 
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); 
#else 
    LabelLoader ll = new LabelLoader(); 
    ll.Start(); 
#endif
```

If you are in debug mode that means your main method is this:

```
    LabelLoader ll = new LabelLoader(); 
    ll.Start();
```

This means that once it has run these two lines the program finishes running and presumably exits. It doesn't matter what your timer is up to, the program has quit and thus your timer never fires.

I'd advise testing your ll with a better harness. Personally I use a winform type interface and just have a start button to mimic the service start (which will then have your code in the button click). Once I think I have that code running as I want I then test it in a service environment.

Comment: Yes, that is my Main() code.  This is my first win service so I'm not sure the proper way to debug & test.  Can you expand on what you mean by testing it in a service environment?  The code in the service works how I want it to, its just the timer not firing issue.  So what would my next steps be?

Comment: Basically by "in a service environment" I mean by installing your code as a service and let windows start it up. So I'd ditch your debug code and just let the service run and persist itself as it would in the live environment. Run it as a service on your computer and just test it that way. You can still attach a debugger to it (via attach to process) if you need to debug it.

Comment: Installed it works fine, thanks!  Must be how I was debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

"If Enabled is set to true and AutoReset is set to false, the Timer raises the Elapsed event only once, the first time the interval elapses. When Enabled is true and AutoReset is true, the Timer continues to raise the Elapsed event on the specified interval."

So I think you gotta set

```
timer.AutoReset = true;
```

Comment: timer.Enabled is the same as timer.Start, which I have in my SetTimer method.

Comment: I set  timer.AutoReset = true;  and no change.  The  timer_Elapsed method never gets called.

Comment: Wait. Why do you set Elapsed every time. Don't do that.

Comment: Thats right, I moved it out of SetTimer().  Still not firing the event though.

Comment: To comment on the original post you only need to set timer.autoreset = true if you want the thing to keep repeating. If you only want that timer to run once it can be set to false. The value of this certainly wouldn't make a difference to the first time it runs.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for anyone else with the same problem I was able to work around this by using;

```
public void StartTimer()
{
    _timer.Interval = _pollingIntervalMilliseconds;
    _timer.Enabled = true;
    _timer.AutoReset = false; // We must manually restart the timer when we have finished processing
    _timer.Elapsed += CheckForUpdates;
    _timer.Start();
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System now running, press a key to Stop");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
private void CheckForUpdates(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Checking For Update");
    DoSomethingSlow();
    _timer.Start(); // restarts the timer to hit this method again after the next interval
}
```

It will keep hitting the Elapsed Event until you hit a key to exit